# I have a custom expression program with a lexer, parser and evaluator. How do I LINQ-ify it?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Here are my interfaces and enum, dumbed down slightly. :

```
public interface IExpression
{
    ExpressionType ExpressionType { get; }
}

public interface ILiteralExpression : IExpression
{
    object Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IOperatorExpression : IExpression
{
    IExpression[] Operands { get; set; }

    string OperatorUniqueName { get; set; }

    IOperatorExpression SetOperand(int index, IExpression expression);
}

public enum ExpressionType
{
    Operator,
    Literal
}
```

To create an expression, I can do something like this:

```
var expression = ExpressionManager.Engines["Default"].Parser.Parse("1 + 3 * 4 + \"myVariable\"");
```

Which is equivalent to something like this:

```
var expression1 = ExpressionManager.CreateOperator("Add", 2).
    SetOperand(0, ExpressionManager.CreateOperator("Add", 2).
        SetOperand(0, ExpressionManager.CreateLiteral(1)).
        SetOperand(1, ExpressionManager.CreateOperator("Multiply", 2).
            SetOperand(0, ExpressionManager.CreateLiteral(3)).
            SetOperand(1, ExpressionManager.CreateLiteral(4)))).
    SetOperand(1, ExpressionManager.CreateLiteral("myVariable"));
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this (efficiently):

```
(from e in expression
 where e is ILiteralExpression && "myVariable".Equals(((ILiteralExpression)e).Value)
 select (ILiteralExpression)e).ToList().
 ForEach(e => e.Value = 2);
```

I think I need to do some implementing of `IQueryable` or something, but I'm not sure where to start.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walk your expression tree, and convert each element to an object from the [`System.Linq.Expressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) namespace, using the factory methods of the [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) class.

If you cannot modify your `IExpression` class to add methods that let you implement the [*visitor pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), you can rely on type checking the old style:

```
private static Expression ConvertExpression(IExpression expr) {
    if (expr is ILiteralExpression) {
        return Expression.Constant(((ILiteralExpression)expr).Value);
    }
    if (expr is IOperatorExpression) {
        var ops = ((IOperatorExpression)expr)
            .Operands
            .Select(ConvertExpression)
            .ToList();
        var res = ops[0];
        for (int i = 1 ; i != ops.Length ; i++) {
            if (((IOperatorExpression)expr).OperatorUniqueName == "+") {
                res = Expressions.Add(res, ops[i]);
            } else if (((IOperatorExpression)expr).OperatorUniqueName == "-") {
                res = Expressions.Subtract(res, ops[i]);
            } else if (...) {
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Of course you'll need a lot more logic in this method. The crucial part is passing parameters: you need to figure out where your variables are and what is their type, use `Expression.ParameterExpression` to create it, and then compile your converted expression into a `Func<...>` of some sort using the [`LambdaExpression.Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx) method. With a compiled lambda in hand, you can plug in your expressions into LINQ's in-memory framework.

If you can make your `IExpressions` visitable, add a visitor that walks the expression and converts it to a LINQ expression using a stack.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is build your own LINQ Query Provider. You can choose what LINQ operations you want to allow (WHERE, OrderBy, etc.)

This is the blog post series that helped me the most when I wrote one:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx